# Devise doesn't validate registration form after I change the default registration routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've got a simple app (Rails 3.2) with a User modal that's set up with devise(version 2.0.4).

My User model has the devise default settings:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Everything seems to work fine when I use the default devise routes like so:

```
devise_for :users
```

But I didn't to use the default so I changed it to this ones:

```
devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "sign_up" }
```

After I changed this routes and restarted my server they seem to work fine but for some reason the validation don't work now, and even if I remove the "validatable" feature from my model and add my own custom validation they does not seem to work as well.

Would love your help on this!
- Paz

Comment: **Note:** This seems to work if I remove the _":path"_ attribute from the routes but the problem is that I have to use my custom routes with the _"users/login"_ instead of just _"/login"_

Answer (score 1):

**Solved this**. The reason why it didn't work is because devise uses the "users/login" to know on what scope to work on.

So in order to fix this I changed my routes file to this:

```
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
  get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
  get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  get "/register" => "devise/registrations#new"
end
```

**Reference:** https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes